# I can't add a custom label on the map

Tags: java, geotools

I want to add a custom label which would contain param1 on the map. So, I created a datastore from the .csv file, added my custom parameters to the SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder as properties and created a TextSymbolizer. But I've got only lat/lon parameters on my map. What do I do wrong?

```
SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder b = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();

    b.setName("MyFeatureType");
    b.setCRS(crs);
    b.add("location", Point.class);
    b.add("param1", String.class);
    b.add("param2", Double.class);
    final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = b.buildFeatureType();

    SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);
    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

    Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate( coordinate.getX(), coordinate.getY()));
    featureBuilder.add(point);
    SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
    DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection("internal", TYPE);
    featureCollection.add(feature);
```

//        Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(TYPE,Color.GREEN);

```
    StyleBuilder styleBuilder = new StyleBuilder();
    FilterFactory ff = styleBuilder.getFilterFactory();
    Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(TYPE, Color.GREEN);
    style.setName("MyStyle");
    TextSymbolizer textSymb = styleBuilder.createTextSymbolizer(Color.black, styleBuilder.createFont("Arial", 10),
        "fred");
    textSymb.setLabel(ff.function("Concatenate", ff.function("getX", ff.property("location")), ff.literal(" "),
        ff.function("getY", ff.property("location")), ff.literal(" "), ff.function("env", ff.property("param1")), 
        ff.literal(" "), ff.function("env", ff.property("param2"))));
    //textSymb.setHalo(styleBuilder.createHalo(Color.white, 1));
    style.featureTypeStyles().get(0).rules().get(0).symbolizers().add(textSymb);

    Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, style);
```

here is the fragment of my .csv file

```
LAT,LON,param1,param2,param3,param4,param5
27.0,-30.0,280.9,-6.37312,-1.79618,6.621398154805826,74.2571170243146,
27.0,-27.0,281.1,-6.43312,-2.77618,7.006582132534355,66.65431728639881,
27.0,-24.0,281.3,-4.54312,-3.10618,5.50347827615005,55.63552261029227,
27.0,-21.0,281.1,-3.38312,-3.72618,5.032881324695736,42.23329167237091,
27.0,-18.0,280.7,-2.34312,-4.09618,4.718990859456285,29.766254126085926,
27.0,-15.0,280.3,-2.90312,-3.95618,4.907080650538935,36.26771217705186,
27.0,-12.0,280.0,-4.31312,-4.31618,6.101834652637045,44.97572026458005,
27.0,-9.0,279.2,-5.72312,-4.12618,7.055454644009236,54.20595659912361,
27.0,-6.0,279.3,-6.43312,-3.90618,7.526171230830957,58.73038946633453,
27.0,-3.0,279.4,-8.03312,-4.58618,9.250083120363465,60.27405416053762,
27.0,0.0,279.7,-8.76312,-4.05618,9.656336569885982,65.15865639285987,
27.0,3.0,283.7,-8.00312,-1.12618,8.081968231070002,81.98720020607146,
27.0,6.0,284.8,-6.68312,1.19382,6.788910822952606,100.1257130758201,
27.0,9.0,284.8,-4.84312,3.27382,5.84583022595845,124.05602094541278
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are using the [`env` function](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#environment-function) to access an "environment" variable rather than the property you want. So modifying your label expression to

```
Expression label = ff.function("Concatenate", ff.function("getX", ff.property("location")), ff.literal(" "),
    ff.function("getY", ff.property("location")), ff.literal(" "), ff.property("param1"), ff.literal(" "),
    ff.property("param2"));
```

will produce the label you want.

[image]

You can also make life easier for yourself by using a [`CSVDataStore`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/datastore/intro.html) to read in your file.

```
File file = new File(fileName);
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(CSVDataStoreFactory.URL_PARAM.key, URLs.fileToUrl(file));
params.put(CSVDataStoreFactory.STRATEGYP.key, CSVDataStoreFactory.SPECIFC_STRATEGY);
params.put(CSVDataStoreFactory.LATFIELDP.key, "LAT");
params.put(CSVDataStoreFactory.LnGFIELDP.key, "LON");
ds = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
```